# php-login.net MVC login script gives a 500 error

Tags: php, apache

Hello I've recently downloaded the login system from php-login.net from github. Just having a play at the moment I have set-up the code on my local dev using xampp and vhosts (mvclogin.dev). When I visit the address the home page loads as expected but when I move away to any other page it throws and intern server error:

```
"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an   ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

I know a few other people have been having this issue and posted on blogs by the developer but the developer simply answers "it works on my server so its your server thats problem" so I'm pretty stuck at what I should be troubleshooting.

PHP Error: Log

```
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:15.039636 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1764] [client 127.0.0.1:56913] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:15.039636 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1764] [client 127.0.0.1:56913] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:16.116697 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1772] [client 127.0.0.1:56914] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://mvclogin.dev/
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:16.116697 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1772] [client 127.0.0.1:56914] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://mvclogin.dev/
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:16.168700 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1748] [client 127.0.0.1:56916] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Nov 05 15:40:16.168700 2013] [core:error] [pid 7020:tid 1748] [client 127.0.0.1:56916] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: Is there anything in the PHP error log?

Comment: added error log to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, the .htaccess file he has set the RewriteBase to a sample URL. Simply remove this leaving the forward slash.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Thanks @Moshe Katz for pushing me in the right direction